# Add custom symbol/icon to font

Tags: ios, icons, symbols, uifont

I am wondering if it is possible to add small icons, that are available as png files, during launch time to a custom font I use in my app? The code should work on iOS5 and above. This would have several use cases. For example you could add labels with icons without using an image view and a label and layouting the stuff based on the text. I know that I have read somewhere, that apple uses this technique on their own apps, but I don't know if they add the icons on launch time or already in the design process into the font.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have simulated this by using a custom view that has a string and font property as well as one or more images. Create a mapping between special char values and images. In drawrect use the uikit category on NSString that lets you draw chars or strings. When u get to your special char you skip it and draw the image. Those draw methods return the size of the string/char so you can tell how much to move as you draw.

You can see this technique used on github, look for the CreditCard ObjectiveC. It's used to draw placeholders or chars in the PlaceHolder class

Comment: That would be an approach, however this won't work with UIKit Elements such as Buttons, TabBar Items, Bar Button Items and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to add png to font in device. Font file use vector graphics to represent every glyph. You can convert font file to SVG. But PNG is not vector graphics.

I use icon font in some of my projects. I have create a project to use icon font easily. https://github.com/JohnWong/IconFont. Icon font is always used in UILabel by setting text. But I think creating a UIImage from font is more flexible. UIImage can be used in Buttons, TabBar Items, Bar Button Items and so on. This is why I create this project. The README of this project is written in Chinese. But the demo project will show everything clearly.